# Remove unwanted spaces in Bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, citing, miktex, urls

I'm referencing a URL in the following way:

`\bibitem{r10} PC Magazine \emph{https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/37919/application-program}, 2011`

The output is something like this:

[image]

***I tried to remove the spaces after PC and Magazine, but to no avail. How can I do it?*** Thanks!

Comment: Seems you should use `\raggedright` for you bibliography. But this is very speculative, because we would need a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) and some information about the expected result. Currently I even do not know whether or not you are using a manually made bibliography or `bibtex` (but it seems you are not using `biblatex`). BTW: Why don't you use `\url` (from either [`url`](https://ctan.org/pkg/url) or [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref))?

Comment: you should not use `\emph` to mark an URL, use `\url` from the `url` package.  It does not guarantee a better line break, but it know legal break points in URLs

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks for your comment and suggestion. I'm a beginner with Latex. I would definitely follow your advice. Thanks!

Comment: @daleif, thanks for your comment. I'll do what you suggested.